# Getting ValueError while creating VRT using Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, vrt, valueerror

I am trying to create a VRT file using Python (GDAL). I am getting the following error:

> "ValueError: array larger than output file, or offset off edge".

How to solve this error?

The code written for the same is as follows.

```py
import osr
import gdal
import numpy as np
from gdalconst import *

ds = gdal.Open('/home/vigna/Downloads/2740115314.GMODO-SVM12_npp_d20170824_t0721423_e0727209_b30176_c20170824140610010359_nobc_ops.h5')

subds = ds.GetSubDatasets()
#print(subds)
bt = gdal.Open('HDF5:"/home/vigna/Downloads/2740115314.GMODO-SVM12_npp_d20170824_t0721423_e0727209_b30176_c20170824140610010359_nobc_ops.h5"://All_Data/VIIRS-M12-SDR_All/BrightnessTemperature')
bt_array = bt.ReadAsArray()
#print(bt_array)
long = gdal.Open('HDF5:"/home/vigna/Downloads/2740115314.GMODO-SVM12_npp_d20170824_t0721423_e0727209_b30176_c20170824140610010359_nobc_ops.h5"://All_Data/VIIRS-MOD-GEO_All/Longitude')
long_array = long.ReadAsArray()
lat = gdal.Open('HDF5:"/home/vigna/Downloads/2740115314.GMODO-SVM12_npp_d20170824_t0721423_e0727209_b30176_c20170824140610010359_nobc_ops.h5"://All_Data/VIIRS-MOD-GEO_All/Latitude')
lat_array = lat.ReadAsArray()

def raster(ds):
    xsize = ds.RasterXSize
    ysize = ds.RasterYSize
    GeoT = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    Projection = osr.SpatialReference()
    Projection.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjectionRef())
    DataType = 'UInt16'
    X_dataset=long_array
    Y_dataset=lat_array
    return xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection,DataType,X_dataset,Y_dataset

def Create_vrt(Name, Array, driver,xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection,X_dataset,Y_dataset):
#for DataType:
    DataType = gdal.GDT_Float32
    NewFileName = 'bt3'+'.vrt'
    DataSet = driver.Create( NewFileName, xsize,ysize, 1, DataType )
        # the '1' is for band 1.
    DataSet.SetGeoTransform(GeoT)
    DataSet.SetProjection( Projection.ExportToWkt() )
    # Write the array
    DataSet.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( Array )
    return NewFileName

DataSet = ds
Band = DataSet.GetRasterBand(1)
# Open as an array.
Array = bt_array
NewArray = Array
print(NewArray)
xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType, X_dataset, Y_dataset = raster(ds)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('VRT')
NewFileName = Create_vrt('bt3', NewArray, driver, xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, X_dataset, Y_dataset)
#Create_vrt()
print("ok")
```

Comment: You can't write an array to a VRT. A VRT is a [virtual raster](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) (just a small XML text file). Write to something like a GeoTIFF instead.

Comment: If you don't want to write a GeoTIFF to the disk, you could use the MEM (in-memory raster) driver (`driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM')`), or write a GeoTIFF to the `/vsimem` virtual in-memory filesystem (`driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTIFF')`; `driver.Create('/vsimem/some.tiff', etc...)`)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend as suggested here: [Python GDAL: Save array as raster with projection from other file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58517/python-gdal-save-array-as-raster-with-projection-from-other-file)

> write the array as a raster
>
> ```
> def array_to_raster(array):
>     """Array > Raster
>     Save a raster from a C order array.
>
>     :param array: ndarray
>     """
>     dst_filename = '/a_file/name.tiff'
> ```